# MySQL Count and SUM from second table with group by

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to get sales and quantity sale by crossing two tables, group by the first one and sum from the second one.

First table has sales/operations: id_sales, sales_rep
Second table has sales details: id_sales_details, id_sales, quantity

What I need to know is how many operations had each sales_rep and what was the total quantity sum of all those sales.

This MySQL query gives me the first part:

```
SELECT sales.sales_rep, count(*) AS sales
from sales
Group by sales_rep
Order by sales DESC
```

What I cannot solve is how to add to that query the second part I need. The result should look something like:

sales_rep    sales    quantity
Claire             4          13
Peter              2          18
Mary              1           8
John              1           7

Here's a Fiddle to make things clearer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/708234/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.sales_rep, count(*) AS operations, sum(d.quantity)
  from sales s, sales_details d 
   where s.id_sales = d.id_sales 
   Group by s.sales_rep 
   Order by operations DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works very well and I think is efficient too.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution

```
SELECT w.sales_rep, w.sales, SUM(quantity) as quantity
FROM
(SELECT s.sales_rep, t.sales,d.quantity FROM sales AS s
INNER JOIN  sales_details AS d ON s.id_sales = d.id_sales
INNER JOIN  
  (SELECT sales_rep, count(*) AS sales
   from sales
   Group by sales_rep
   Order by sales DESC ) AS t 
  ON s.sales_rep = t.sales_rep) AS w

  GROUP BY w.sales_rep, w.sales
  ORDER BY w.sales_rep ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. This works too but the previous answer looks cleaner and more efficient. But I do appreciate you answered.